# ¿Como omitir una categoria con rewrite en htaccess con CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Quiero que cuando el usuario escriba:

> url.com/sillones/sillon-herradura/

Se cargue el contenido de:

> url.com/productos/sillones/sillon-herradura/

`sillon-herradura` es un ejemplo, podría ser cualquier producto.

¿Como podría hacerlo?

He realizado lo siguiente pero no me funciona:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^productos/sillones/(.*)$ https://url.com/sillones/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Actualizo por si ayuda, uso CodeIgniter.

Comment: ¿Nadie puede ayudarme?

Comment: Hola, creo que puedo ayudarte, si solo buscas modificar la ruta dame un momento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado la respuesta después de 2 dias, hay que modificar el fichero routes.php

```
$route['sillones/(:any)'] = 'productos/sillones/$1';
```

Comment: iba a responderte eso justamente,

Answer (score 0):

En CodeIgniter para modificar las rutas existe el archivo `routes.php` en la carpeta:

> ...\application\config\routes.php

Justamente este archivo existe para poder acortar tus rutas.

Al abrir el archivo en el código no comentado encontraras algo como:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = 'errors/page_missing';
```

Estas lineas se conocen como *reglas de ruteo personalizadas*. Estas te permiten mapear cualquier URI a cualquier controlador y método, liberándote de la convención normal.

Para acortar la URL de:

> url.com/productos/sillones/sillon-herradura/

a

> url.com/sillones/sillon-herradura/

debes agregar la regla:

```
$route['sillones/(:any)'] = 'productos/sillones/$1';
```